# MySQL constant value in view with specific collation

Tags: mysql, sql, view, collation

I need a view with a constant value, which I'm executing with following code:

```
SELECT Name, 'Unpaid' AS Status FROM table;
```

However the collation is always by default `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
I would need for this constant another collation with `COLLATE` but `SELECT Name, 'Unpaid' COLLATE latin1_general_ci AS Status FROM table;` doesn't work. Is there another way to change the collation to fix a illegal mix of collation?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the exact error message. That will help other users to find this question, when they search for the same error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set both the character set and the collation.  This should work:

```
select name, _latin1 'Unpaid'  COLLATE latin1_general_ci as status
from t;
```

You might be interested in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-introducer.html) for character sets.

Comment: So obscure... Thank you for helping me out!